# Rendering a script bundle within webforms application issue

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, bundle

I have a webforms application, in the master page I have this :

```
    <%: Styles.Render("~/bundles/CssBootstrap") %>  
   <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Query") %>  
  <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
```

In the **BundleConfig.cs** file I have

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
            "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Query").Include(
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/jquery-1.9.1.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/jquery-1.9.1.intellisense.js",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/bootstrap.js" 
            ));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/CssBootstrap").Include(
           "~/Content/bootstrap.css"
           ,"~/Content/bootstrap.css-theme" 
           ));
```

When I run the application, I get this in the source of the page :

```
 <link href="/bundles/CssBootstrap?v=czIWtJIp8NT-Vut_P5jm8e1wcrWStCXZx8WrJTcjZSA1" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/bundles/Query?v="></script>
<script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=_crq2QUT7I_NAMAaEv7T-Hgr0jkqYYHmaNBKKo2em_Q1"></script>
```

The second ScriptBundle `Query` is not working as I think.

1. What is the reason of this error?
2. How Can I fix it?

Comment: Try `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` and see if it makes a difference

Comment: Have you removed the `Query` script references in the `ScriptManager`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing it without extentions as below:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Query").Include(
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/jquery-1.9.1",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/jquery-1.9.1.intellisense",
            "~/Scripts/WebForms/bootstrap" 
            ));
```

Hope it helps...

Thanks.